# how pymongo modify many elements of an array which is a key of document

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I am trying to update some matched elements within an array in a mongodb document.

I want to update all the `comments.$index.author` from `chao` to `tom`, but I can't figure out the syntax.

Here's what I want to do in pseudo-json.

Before:

```
{
 "author" : "lily",
 "contents" : "watch movive",
 "comments" : [
             {
                 "comment" : "good",
                 "author" : "chao",
                 "votes" : 0
             },
             {
                 "comment": "so so",
                 "author": "chao",
                 "votes": 3
             },
             ………………,
             {
                 "comment": "bad",
                 "author": "yong",
                 "votes": -1
             },
         ]
}
```

After:

```
{
"author" : "lily",
"contents" : "watch movive",
"comments" : [
             {
                 "comment" : "good",
                 "author" : "tom",
                 "votes" : 0
             },
             {
                 "comment": "so so",
                 "author": "tom",
                 "votes": 3
             },
             ………………,
             {
                 "comment": "bad",
                 "author": "yong",
                 "votes": -1
             },
         ]
 }
```

Comment: what have you attempted?

Comment: I want to write some python code like this:
    res = db.posts.find()    
    for post in res:      
        NewPost = post       
        for index in range(len(NewPost["comments"])):
            if NewPost["comments"][index]["author"] == "chao":
                NewPost["comments"][index]["author"] = "tom"
        db.posts.update(post, NewPost)
But it failed. Also, I wonder will there be more clever method?